# Strange Paint.setTextSize + Paint.measureText behavior

Tags: android

I want to draw text on a canvas.

- On my Motorola ET1 Tablet:

If I try `paint.setTextSize`(**1**) then `paint.measureText`("18.62") returns **2.52**.

If I try `paint.setTextSize`(**0.99**f) then `paint.measureText`("18.62") returns **2.44**.

- This is perfectly normal, but now on my Galaxy Note 3 :

If I try `paint.setTextSize`(**1**) then `paint.measureText`("18.62") returns **3**.

If I try `paint.setTextSize`(**0.99f**) then `paint.measureText`("18.62") returns **161** !

Edit : For the sake of comprehensiveness, flag `Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG` is on.

Comment: Strange indeed, did you try to run this test on an emulator or some other device?

Comment: Not really, I could try..
Inbetween, I realised my issue was related to using Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG when constructing paint object

Comment: I tried with other devices and emulator: from API level 21 onwards, mesureText fails to return correct result for text size < 1 with flag LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG enabled even if flag SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG is enabled

Comment: do you call measureText immediately after you set the size? can you wait a bit and see that the text have been rendered and call it then? It's a long shot, but worth a try.